# How to express: a PC that has no role OR no user

Tags: meaning

When I say: a PC that has no role or user.
The meaning seems to be: the PC has no role, and the PC has no user.

But my intention is: the PC has no role, or the PC has no user.

How can I express that conveniently?

Comment: I don't understand this. If it doesn't do anything, ***and*** nobody uses it, I guess it's ***unused*** (and hopefully not even turned on, if all it's going to do is waste energy). Depending on your point of view, perhaps you could call it *junk tin*, or *spare hardware*. If the PC has a role but no user, perhaps it's a *file server*. If it has a user but no role, the company need to sharpen up on their inventory processing.

Comment: that will be ***A PC that neither has a role nor any user***, but I have never seen a PC like that!

Comment: "A PC that has no role or user" is ambiguous (not a clear statement). It should be either "A PC that has neither a role nor a user" or "A PC that either has no role or no user" (the one you meant to say). That's plain English. By the way, writing advice is also off-topic on ELU.

Comment: PCs do not have roles. The sentence does not make any sense whatsoever—if you could tell us what you are actually trying to say, perhaps we can phrase it in a way that is actually English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is a bit awkward, and I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but my best stab at it would be to work in the word "either" somewhere to draw extra attention to the fact that it as an "or" relationship rather than an "and" relationship

Comment: "A PC either has no role or no user." sounds clear enough or still ambiguous?

Comment: Maybe...

"A PC either has no role, or, it has no user"

The commas will definitely draw extra attention the the fact that it's "one or the other", and referring to the PC again with the word "it" should further help distinguish your meaning.

Answer (score 3):

English lacks clear, unambiguous logical OR operators, unlike languages like Lojban, for instance, which are designed for unambiguous communication of logical ideas.  Of course, you could always write down your ideas in logical notation or pseudocode if you're going to go that far.

To be clear, it seems like what you're trying to express could be written in pseudocode as:

```
(NOT role) XOR (NOT user)
```

There are a number of ways you might make it clearer.

**Add "Either"**

Like Justin just pointed out, "either" may make the exclusive nature of the "or" more clear:

> The computer has either no role, or no user.

**Remove the Negatives**

Students of logic will notice that my pseudocode above could be made simpler, but logically identical:

```
role XOR user
```

So the negatives in your phrase may be complicating things unnecessarily.

> "The computer has either a role or a user."

This is technically the same thing, but it's easier for humans to understand.

**Add a Clarifying Phrase**

You could add a phrase to the end.  For instance:

> "The computer has a role or a user, but not both."

Pseudocode:

```
(role OR user) AND NOT (role AND user)
```

This is far more complicated in code, but for some reason it makes the point clearer to a human listener by breaking it down a little bit.

**Combine All Three Techniques**

It's tempting for a technically trained individual to express something as concisely as possible because that's good, clear, elegant design.  Computers don't need clarification; they're perfect listeners.  When you're talking to people, though, it can pay to be a little bit redundant:

> "The computer has either a role or a user, but not both."

**What Not to Do**

*Do not* add the clarifying phrase without removing the negatives.  That would be:

> "The computer has no role or no user, but not neither."

Goodness, I don't ever want my job to rely on parsing that word-salad.

For interest, the pseudocode for the above abomination reads:

```
(NOT role OR NOT user) AND NOT (role NOR user)
```

You can chain negatives and qualifiers indefinitely whilst retaining identical logical implications.  For instance, to be expressed without NOR, you need to say:

```
(NOT role OR NOT user) AND NOT (NOT role AND NOT user)
```

Do not write, speak or code this way.  Even the Vulcans are getting annoyed with us, now.

**Context is More Important than All of the Above**

Far more important than the above discussion of logical expressions, is why you're saying what you're saying.  It's clear what the absolute logical meaning of the isolated phrase should be, but without knowing the message you're trying to convey, it's impossible to say what you should write.

For instance if you are emphasising that the computer is missing something, then use that word.

> "The computer is missing either a role or a user."

Instead, if you are specifying that the computer is in this state by design, maybe use the word "should".

> "The computer should have either a role or a user, but not both."

You can see that the meaning of each of the above statements is richer and clearer.  Both technically satisfy the logical relationship `role XOR user`, but their overall meanings are quite different from each other.

Another thing context is important for is understanding the terms you're using.  For instance, I've been using the term "computer" where you used the term "PC".  I assumed PC meant computer because it was associated with the word "user".  However, there are [other meanings for PC](http://www.allacronyms.com/PC).

Comment: Sure, that is one way of complicating things for the poor guy.

Comment: I tried to keep it as clear as possible by giving examples.  I got the vibe from the question that he was focused on the logical grammatical construct, which is why I addressed that first, then explained a better way to think about it, which is to contextualise the information.

Comment: Also, the thoroughness of the logical discussion was intended as a bit of a reductio ad absurdum of what happens when you focus on the logic devoid of context.